# Uploading Repo Changes to Remote Server via FTP using DevOp

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am new to Azure Devops and i am trying to update the changes from the Repo to the  production website via Azure Devops through ftp since its on a remote server / different host.

**i am using Upload Via FTP Task but iam getting the following error :**

/azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 3, Col: 1): A sequence was not expected

**this the YAML Task :**

```
# FTP upload
# Upload files using FTP
- task: FtpUpload@2
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: 'inputs'
    serverUrl: 'serverurl'
    username: 'username'
    password: 'mypass'
    rootDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Directoryname'
    filePatterns: '**'
    remoteDirectory: 'ftp url link'
    clean: false
    cleanContents: false
    preservePaths: false
    trustSSL: false
```

The Repo is is done and Using Default Agent

I am not sure if i am missing something or there is an alternative way.

Help is Appreciated.

Thanks

Edit :

```
    # Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    inputs:
      credentialsOption: 'inputs'
      serverUrl: 'input'
      username: 'input'
      password: 'input'
      rootDirectory: 'input'
      filePatterns: '**'
      remoteDirectory: 'input'
      clean: false
      cleanContents: false
      preservePaths: false
      trustSSL: false
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

Updated YAML, no more errors but no result in the remote ftp or files being uploaded

Comment: Your YAML appears to be incorrect (in the edit section) as the entire `script` contains all the `inputs` as a string. (StackOverflow's syntax highlighter shows it all in green, while the `displayName:` field is in blue as desired.) This is just basic YAML syntax, you'll need to get that right before the azure pipeline can work.

Answer (score 0):

Below steps can successfully upload the files on my side.

1, Make sure your FTP url, username and password is correct(Make sure you can do it on local firstly.)

1, Create an FTP service connection on DevOps Project-level settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

2, Create a repo that contains the files that you want to use FTP to upload:

This is the structure on my side:

[image]

3, Set up a pipeline based on this repo:

[image]

[image]

[image]

4, Use the below pipeline YAML definition to replace the previous content and then run the pipeline.

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- task: FtpUpload@2
  displayName: 'FTP Upload: FTPUploadFolder'
  inputs:
    serverEndpoint: 'FTPTo_testbowman1'
    rootDirectory: FTPUploadFolder
    remoteDirectory: this_is_remote_dir
```

[image]

5, you can see that the entire folder uploaded successfully:

[image]

Let me know if you have more concerns.